# Override PHP interpreter PHPUnit options

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I need to use port 9001 for my CLI xdebug.

By default, when I debug from PhpStorm, these options are sent:

```
-dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --no-configuration --filter "/::get_me( .*)?$/"
```

So I need to replace 9000 to 9001.

I tried adding `xdebug.remote_port` option in "CLI Interpreters -> Configuration Options", but instead of overriding it just appends it.

Any idea where can I just override it instead of append it?

I don't want to change the general xdebug port config, since php-fpm uses port 9000.

Comment: *"I don't want to change the general xdebug port config, since php-fpm uses port 9000."* Could you please explain this part -- it does not make much sense to me right now -- if php-fpm uses the same port as xdebug .. then you **need** to change xdebug port.

Comment: As for xdebug port -- `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug` -- changing xdebug port for whole project.

Comment: *"I tried adding xdebug.remote_port option in "CLI Interpreters -> Configuration Options", but instead of overriding it just appends it."* AFAIK newer value should override old one during run time so it's OK to have it like that.

Comment: Well, funny enough xdebug over php-fpm works well on port 9000. xdebug over cli does not. I keep getting "Connection with xdebug '2.5.0' was not established."  But if I change the xdebug port to 9001 on phpstorm and it works.
This is the log from xdebug: http://pastebin.com/SWeMm5fn

These are my xdebug cli settings:
http://pastebin.com/iMSW7Qkx

Comment: *"xdebug over php-fpm works well on port 9000. xdebug over cli does not."* you meant to say -- "work when debugging over browser and not when doing in a CLI". It could be because of `xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1` -- better set it to `0` and set correct IP manually (`xdebug.remote_host`). If I'm correct then if you collect xdebug log for "xdebug over php-fpm" then you may see different IP address autodetected there .. so specifying right IP manually should help. But when working with php-fpm changing xdebug to 9001 is the best solution.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with this as well. The issue is not just the port, but when using remote debug, the PHPUnit tester forcibly adds the `remote_host` and `remote_port` to the command. If you are fortunate enough to have the IP actually point to your computer, you can enable the `Can accept external connections` option. I'm not that fortunate, so I need to keep looking.